# ImportError: cannot import name from __init__.py

Tags: python-3.x

I have a project structure as the following

```
src/
  scripts/
    script1
  mylib
    __init__.py
    a_module.py
```

These are the contents of `__init__.py`

```
__version__ = '0.0.1'
```

But if I try to do this on `script1`:

```
from mylib import __version__ as _ver
```

It fails with this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script1", line 2, in <module>
    from mylib import __version__ as _ver
ImportError: cannot import name '__version__'
```

Changing the var name doesn't help at all, i.e. this fails, too:

```
from mylib import a_ver as _ver
```

Every other variable in any other module gets imported correctly, e.g.

```
from mylib.a_module import a_var
```

Why? And how can I work around this?

Comment: Are you sure you called the file `__init__.py`, and not `__init.py__` or `_init_.py` or something?

Comment: What does `import mylib`, then `print(mylib)` show was imported? Is that the right file?

Comment: I am running the script from sing pycharm run, so pythonpath gets set to my projects src root, however, I noticed that an outdated version of the package is stuck in my local users site-packages, and the `__init__.py` there indeed does not define `__version__`, however the package isn't listed and pip uninstall returns `Cannot uninstall requirement mypackage, not installed`, this module was obscuring the path of my local module

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```py
import mylib
_ver = mylib.__version__
del mylib
```